# arranging teachers and students around a circular table with at least 10 students between teachers

Tags: combinatorics

A course has $14$ teachers and $280$ students. how many ways are there to sit them around a circular table (meaning rotated arrangements are the same) so that there are at least $10$ students between every couple of teachers?

My idea is twofold: I'll first arrange the teachers and then multiply that by the arrangements for students between teachers. First there are $13!$ ways to sit the teachers around the table. Now we don't need to think of it as a table anymore: we simply have 13 gaps in which we need to put 280 students, with 10 students in each gap.

My first thought was to now formulate the question as $x_1+x_2+...+x_{13} = 280$ where $x_i \ge 10 $. now I can define $y_i=x_i-10$ and get $y_1+y_2+...+y_{13} = 150$ where $y_i\ge 0$, which the answer for is $C(180+13-1,150)=C(162,150)$. But I believe the teachers and students in the question are each unique, so I don't think I can formulate the question with this equation. We care about the order between students and there is no repetition, so the formula is $P(n,k)$. But how do I use the fact that there are at least 10 students between teachers?

thanks

Comment: Often in problems involving circular tables one declares that arrangements that differ by a rotation are equivalent. Is that your intention here?  And what do you mean by saying that there are $13!$ ways to sit the teachers?

Comment: That's exactly the place in which I use the rotation. There are 14 teachers and there are (14-1)! ways to sit them around a circular table. Now we tend to put the students in between the teachers

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  If you are assuming that rotated arrangements are the same, you need to actually say that.  Don't make your readers guess what you are assuming.  And I still don't understand what you mean about $13!$  Are you just saying that there are $13!$ ways to order the teachers other than the special one?

Comment: Anyway, once you have the teachers sorted and a gap sequence selected, there are $280!$ ways to populate the gaps.

Comment: I mean to say that there are 13! unique ways to arrange the teachers around the table, when rotated arrangements are the same. There are 280! ways to populate the gaps if there aren't any conditions, but here the condition is that in each gap there are at least 10 students.

Comment: There are far more than $13!$ ways to arrange the teachers at the table...I agree that there are $13!$ ways to put the remaining teachers in order.  And the $280!$ is the number of ways to populate the gaps assuming a gap sequence has been specified.

Comment: I did edit it. I'll try to explain my reasoning better (also in the post). what I meant to do is 2 fold: first arrange the teachers (13!) and then multiply that by the students arrangement. maybe it's incorrect to do it in this way.

Comment: That's a good start but you still need to populate the gaps, and there are $280!$ ways to do that.  So, you are off by a multiplicative factor of $280!$

Comment: I believe there are less than 280! ways to do that. for example sitting all the students between 2 teaches isn't allowed, since between all other teachers there will be 0 students.

Comment: After the teachers have been placed, there are $280$ seats.  You can number them from $1$ to $280$ if you like.  There are $280$ distinct students who must go in those seats.  There are $280!$ ways to do that.

Comment: I think you are missing a part of the question. between each 2 teachers we need to put at least 10 students.

Comment: Again, you place the teachers and create the gaps with that constraint in mind.  Once you have done that, you have left $280$ unoccupied seats and there are $280!$ ways to occupy them.  I suggest:  take smaller numbers and work this out by hand to convince yourself that nothing has been missed.

Comment: Note:  There are in fact $14$ gaps...not sure why you think there are $13$.  The special teacher doesn't count for the ordering of the teachers, but there are still $14$ gaps.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The analysis as presented is a good start but there's a numerical error and it is incomplete.

We start by putting some designated special teacher at the head of the table.  That fixes the rotation.  There are then $13$ teachers left, so $13!$ ways to order them.

There are $14$ gaps (not $13$ as stated in the post) so we have $a_1, \cdots, a_{14}$ with $a_i≥10$ for all $i$ and $\sum a_i=280$.  As suggested by the OP, it is useful to define $A_i=a_i-10$ so that the $A_i$ are all non-negative integers which sum to $140$.  Stars and Bars then tells us that there are $$\binom {140+14-1}{14-1}=\binom {153}{13}$$ valid gap sequences.

Of course, there are $280!$ ways to fill the gaps with students (take any ordering of the students, the first $a_1$ of them go, in order, to the gap between the special teacher and the next one, and so on).  Thus the answer is $$\boxed{13!\times \binom {153}{13}\times 280!\approx 2.5\times 10^{593}}$$

Comment: If we first choose the students that fill the gaps, and then order them inside the gaps, is it still 280! ? shouldn't we do the ordering inside each gap? for example if the first 3 gaps are filled with 10, 20, 30 students I would think we would have multiplied by 10!20!30! no? and I don't think we get the same answer by doing 280!

Comment: Again, you have $280$ seats numbered (clockwise say) from $1$ to $280$.  The fact that you put markers at various places around the circle is irrelevant (to this part).  Please, follow my earlier suggestion.  Take smaller numbers and work it out by hand to persuade yourself that this is correct.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot.